# QT add Label to a page of stacked widget

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel

I am trying to create a UI in QT C++. I have a stacked widget and it has many pages in it. I want to add a new label to the 5th page(page5) of the stacked widget. It should be visible in the UI. How can i add a dynamically created label to that page?

```
QLabel *label = new QLabel(this);
label->setFrameStyle(QFrame::Panel | QFrame::Sunken);
label->setText("first line\nsecond line");
label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignBottom | Qt::AlignRight);
//Here is how to change position:
label->setGeometry(QRectF(10,10,30,80));
```

this code might create the label but how to show this  in the 5th page of my stacked widget.

Thank you and regards.

Comment: your question is unclear

Comment: Where is the stacked widget? How do you add the label to it?

Comment: Every widget which is added to the stacked widget becomes a page on its own. ([QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html#details)) If you intend to add the label to a specific page this means you have to add the label to the resp. widget which forms the 5th page. And, btw. `label->setGeometry(QRectF(10,10,30,80));`? Can't you use a layout to arrange your widgets?

Comment: I am using QT created for the designing. But there is a situation were i have to create a label dynamically. As @Scheff'sCat has said i want to add the label to the respective widget. But i don't know how to add it. I need help in this part.

Comment: currently this code places QLabel into whatever widget this code is in (`this` pointer is used). Did you subclass stacked widget? Usually that's unneeded, instead each page is formed by a QFrame which contains respective controls. QFrames can be loaded from .ui.

Comment: The widgets loaded from the UI (designer) are accessible and can be retrieved in C++ (at runtime). (I don't have experience with UI designer but have seen numerous examples here and elsewhere.) Once, you retrieved the widget pointer you can use it like any widget (pointer) which was created in C++ code.

Comment: FYI: [Using a Designer UI File in Your C++ Application](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html)

Comment: Just pass the desired widget ptr as parent to QLabel. Where that piece of code in the question comes from? MainWindow maybe? - then just find the parent widget from your UI ptr.